# can not find the function on disk even though it is being imported

Tags: python, django

django manage.py imports a function `execute_manager`

using `from django.core.management import execute_manager`

but when i browse to `django->core->management` directory there is no file present as `execute_manager` why is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's defined in `__init__.py`.

[Python Tutorial, §6.4, "Packages"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)